# DataTables + ServerSide: Child Rows destroyed

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the [DataTables jQuery plugin](https://datatables.net/) with server side pagination to create a table with child rows where the user can change the data, the problem I have is when I move to another page without saving changes in the modified forms; the DataTables removes the rows and its child rows from the DOM, so I am not able to get later the updated rows to save the changes, also if I move back to the first page where the user modified the data, the child rows are re-created (as part of the createdRow event where I am creating the child rows) so the changes entered by the user are lost.

Is there any way to deal with this problem?

Comment: You may want to execute some logic on your webpage's "unload" event. See [jQuery's unload](https://api.jquery.com/unload/) - since you're already referencing jQuery. More generally, [look here](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+before+page+unload&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough experience in working with DataTable, but I guess this plugin has something like "data is loaded" event. Before the page is reloaded, you can save your draft data in separate array/object (like `draftData`) and after data is loaded, you can merge information before page rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own logic since this is an expected behavior of the DataTables plugin.
When using server side with DataTables, the plugin doesn't have a way to identify or "remember" what rows are being modified, what rows are selected, etc. Because of each pagination request rebuild the table and re-create the rows.
I found somewhere that a valid approach was using a global variable to store all the changes (selected rows, updated data, etc) I am also using the createdRow event to restore the changes made by the user after creating each row.

Comment: Thanks for writing down how you got round the issue. It would be amazing if you packaged up this code and published it as a plugin for datatables, or at least pasted the function here so that others can see the code :)